# Can not get json from mangopay post card response

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, response, mangopay

I'm trying to post a registration card thanks to Mangopay API (here is the Postcard route info: https://docs.mangopay.com/endpoints/v2.01/cards#e1042_post-card-info)

```js
fetch(cardRegistration.CardRegistrationURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    accessKeyRef: accessKeyRef,
    data: data,
    cardNumber: cardNumber,
    cardExpirationDate: expiration,
    cardCvx: cvx,
  }).toString(),
});
```

I have a 200 status when I post on this url (https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken) but I can't get data through response.json() and I don't understand why.

Here is the response I get :

```json
{
  "type": "default",
  "status": 200,
  "ok": true,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "map": {
      "server": "Apache",
      "connection": "Keep-Alive",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
      "keep-alive": "timeout=15, max=100",
      "date": "Wed, 22 Sep 2021 15:21:11 GMT",
      "vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent",
      "content-length": "155",
      "content-type": "text/plain"
    }
  },
  "url": "https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken",
  "bodyUsed": false,
  "_bodyInit": {
    "_data": {
      "size": 155,
      "offset": 0,
      "blobId": "415DAFF0-5B8F-429E-91F2-4FC94765A2C2",
      "type": "text/plain",
      "name": "getToken.txt",
      "__collector": {}
    }
  },
  "_bodyBlob": {
    "_data": {
      "size": 155,
      "offset": 0,
      "blobId": "415DAFF0-5B8F-429E-91F2-4FC94765A2C2",
      "type": "text/plain",
      "name": "getToken.txt",
      "__collector": {}
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't continue after calling the JSON method on it.

```js
let card = await postCardResponse.json()
console.log('hello')
```

The console will never show 'hello'.

I tried on postman and I have no problem. However, I am not getting a json but a simple text 'data = ....'. How to retrieve this data via the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You simply have to use response.text() instead of response.json()..